# How could I implement a fuzzy time date replacer using Knockout?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I'd like to implement what this plugin does using jQuery:
https://github.com/rmm5t/jquery-timeago

A short description of that plugin:

This will turn all abbr elements with a class of timeago and an ISO
8601 timestamp in the title (conforming to the datetime design pattern
microformat):

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="2011-12-17T09:24:17Z">December 17, 2011</abbr>
```

Into something like this:

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="December 17, 2011">about 1 day ago</abbr>
```

Except using knockout my markup looks like this:

```
<abbr data-bind="attr: { title: Posted }" class="timeago"></abbr>
```

I think something isn't synced up because nothing is happening even if I put the call to timeago within the viewmodel itself. I'm guessing I need a subscriber that's attached to the observable "Posted" but I'm not sure how to set that up.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your approach doesn't work, because timeago creates a cache via jQuery's data() function. Thus, simply updating the title isn't enough.

I think a custom binding is here the best and cleanest way to go:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.timeago = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var $this = $(element);

        // Set the title attribute to the new value = timestamp
        $this.attr('title', value);

        // If timeago has already been applied to this node, don't reapply it -
        // since timeago isn't really flexible (it doesn't provide a public
        // remove() or refresh() method) we need to do everything by ourselves.
        if ($this.data('timeago')) {
            var datetime = $.timeago.datetime($this);
            var distance = (new Date().getTime() - datetime.getTime());
            var inWords = $.timeago.inWords(distance);

            // Update cache and displayed text..
            $this.data('timeago', { 'datetime': datetime });
            $this.text(inWords);
        } else {
            // timeago hasn't been applied to this node -> we do that now!
            $this.timeago();
        }
    }
};
```

Usage is as simple as this:

```
<abbr data-bind="timeago: Posted"></abbr>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/APRGc/1/

Comment: Will try this here in a few minutes, that was the route that I started down, but wasn't sure. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Replace the line `$this.attr('title', value);` with `$this.attr($.timeago.isTime($this) ? 'datetime' : 'title', value);` so it will work with `<time>`

Comment: It should be noted that timeago only accepts ISO time strings (https://github.com/rmm5t/jquery-timeago/issues/76) so be sure to call .toISOString() on your date object.

Comment: timeago now has an updateFromDOM method that can be used to simplify this code now.  It seems others were trying to get timeago working with knockout binding - see: https://github.com/rmm5t/jquery-timeago/pull/132

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative, that really probably doesn't have any advantage over Niko's answer at all, except perhaps being a touch simpler :) --

```
usf.ko.bindings['timeago'] = {
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    var $element, date;
    date = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    $element = $(element);
    if (date) {
      $element.attr('title', date.toISOString());
      $element.data('tiemago', false);
      return $element.timeago();
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: This solution has one main disadvantage: `timeago('refresh')` means nothing different than `timeago()`, because there is no public "refresh" method. This does essentially mean that every time the observable is updated, a new timer is created with "setInterval" to manage the auto-refresh. So you have a potential memory-leak here.

Comment: @Niko: The `'refresh'` was a typo (wishful thinking?). :) You're right about the setInterval being a potential memory leak. My proposed code should not be used for that reason.